# ¿Qué significa la frase "estamos claro y ya"?

Tags: modismos

En la cancion "X" de Nicky Jam etc escuché la frase:

> Estamos claro y ya.

Yo sé qué significa "Estamos claro", ¿pero qué significa "y ya" al final de la oración?

Comment: Really? And what does it mean? Because "Estamos claro" doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @FGSUZ it's reggaeton, those dude don't even know how to properly talk spanish.

Comment: Ookay, now it makes more sense, but I still can't figure out what they mean haha.

Comment: @Mike To be fair, language is used differently be different people, and right and wrong are much a matter of perspective. Their spanish may be grammatically incorrect, but perhaps "slang-attically" correct? I try to keep an open mind about language and learn all the different ways it is used. I hope we all can respect that. Also, thanks for your answer :)

Comment: is not about slangs, but about uses.
different people has different accents and use of spanish, but the one used in reggaeton is often broken. this happens in the attempt to create rimes and verses and a tight timing during the performance. sometimes because is badly translated english, either way, reggaeton spanish cannot be considered vulgar spanish as it is straight away "broken" spanish born from the puerto rican influence of how english grammar is creating an almost a whole new language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"y ya" in English means "and that's it" y ya